# I want a code page that opens 2 links from one page?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, hyperlink

I have a link, say www.example.com/page.php. If I open this link, then how could it open www.website1.com and www.website2.com
where page.php is where I put the code. 
What I want is code which will redirect to website1 and website2 when I open www.example.com/page.php.
Please give me the code for redirection.

```
window.location = "http://new-website.com";
window.location.href = "http://new-website.com";
window.location.assign("http://new-website.com");
window.location.replace("http://new-website.com");
```

I have searched some codes; will this work?

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        window.open('http://www.website1.com');
        location.href="http://www.website2.com";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Load an html page from php script. it will open a window with one link and redirect current tab to another link.